# Does InvalidateRect() sends WM_PAINT messages to the child controls?

Tags: c, winapi

If I called `InvalidateRect()` on the parent Window, for example:

```
InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
```

What will happen is that inside the `WM_PAINT` handler, `BeginPaint()` will send a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message, which will erase the background, and hence all child controls will disappear.

But the child controls remain when I call `InvalidateRect()`, so does that means `InvalidateRect()` also sends `WM_PAINT` messages to the child controls also?

Comment: @David Heffernan But how the child controls are repainted? I mean if no `WM_PAINT` messages are sent to them.

Comment: First of all, let's make it clear that painting is asynchronous. You call `InvalidateRect`, and nothing happens immediately. Only when the message queue is emptied, are invalid regions repainted. As for child controls, it's complex. DWM composition means that a control may not need to be repainted. The DWM system may already have all it needs and not have any cause to action another `WM_PAINT`. So how this behaves probably depends on whether or not composition or double buffering are active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does InvalidateRect() sends WM_PAINT messages to the child controls?

yes (mostly), its quite clearly described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183426(v=vs.85).aspx

> The system sets the update region for a child window whenever part of the parent window's update region includes a portion of the child window. In such cases, the system first sends a WM_PAINT message to the parent window and then sends a message to the child window, allowing the child to restore any portions of the window that the parent may have drawn over.

but with exception:

> an application cannot generate a WM_PAINT message for the child by invalidating a portion of the parent's client area that lies entirely under the child window. In such cases, neither window receives a WM_PAINT message.

which is actually interesting to know

You can prevent redraw of child windows by setting WS_CLIPCHILDREN to parent window, or by invalidating redraw with the use of RedrawWindow function with RDW_NOCHILDREN flag.